# Как измерить размер текста в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как измерить размер текста в текстбоксе от края первой буквы до края последней?

```
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(str, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us-ru"), FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(this.Name_textBox.FontFamily, this.Name_textBox.FontStyle, this.Name_textBox.FontWeight, this.Name_textBox.FontStretch), Name_textBox.FontSize, Brushes.Black);

double width = formattedText.Width;
```

Этот способ возвращает размер текстбокса, а нужна именно длина текста. Ничего другого не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не по теме: в каком редакторе нарисовали такие стрелки?

Comment: FastStone Capture

Comment: А какая конечная цель-то?

Comment: Сделать чертеж-макет. Т.е. нужно выносные размеры реализовать. А для этого нужно знать конкретно длину самого текста.

Comment: Вы пробовали решения из этого топика? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264398/how-to-calculate-wpf-textblock-width-for-its-known-font-size-and-characters

Comment: @Anton Shakalo  да. конечно. решение из шапки измеряет не то, как я уже говорил. а с glyphTypeface у меня вообще не получилось. На условии  if (!typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface)) возвращает из метода.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Решение простое — нужно создать на основе вашего текста геометрию и просто посмотреть ее границы:

```
var dpiX = 96.0 * VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleX;
var formattedText =
    new FormattedText(
        MyTextBox.Text,
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(
            MyTextBox.FontFamily,
            MyTextBox.FontStyle,
            MyTextBox.FontWeight,
            MyTextBox.FontStretch),
        MyTextBox.FontSize,
        Brushes.Black,
        dpiX);
var geometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point());
var bounds = geometry.Bounds;
MessageBox.Show($"{bounds.Width}");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Полный код примера. Разметка:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Viewbox>
        <Canvas Name="MyCanvas">
            <Path Name="MyPath" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
            <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="0.1" Opacity="0.5">
                <Path.Data>
                    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="MyRect"/>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Text="TT" Margin="0,5"/>
        <Button Content="Click me" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Padding="10,2" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Кодбихайнд:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dpiX = 96.0 * VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleX;
    var formattedText =
        new FormattedText(
            MyTextBox.Text,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(
                MyTextBox.FontFamily,
                MyTextBox.FontStyle,
                MyTextBox.FontWeight,
                MyTextBox.FontStretch),
            MyTextBox.FontSize,
            Brushes.Black,
            dpiX);
    var geometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point());
    var bounds = geometry.Bounds;
    MyCanvas.Height = formattedText.Height;
    MyCanvas.Width = formattedText.Width;
    MyPath.Data = geometry;
    MyRect.Rect = bounds;
    MessageBox.Show($"Ширина форматированного текста: {formattedText.Width}\nШирина границ: {bounds.Width}");
}
```

Comment: GetDpi и DpiScaleX доступны для .NET 4.6.2. Если не сложно, приведите решение для .NET 4.6.

Comment: @UggoFantozzi, посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851003/218063 мне кажется, scaleX, scaleY там, это тоже самое, но доступно с .NET 3

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Но dpiX - это NumberSubstitution, а scaleX, scaleY - double, как тут быть?

Comment: @UggoFantozzi, не понял о чём вы, везде double, вроде: https://docs.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.windows.dpiscale.dpiscalex

Comment: Я об этой строчке: var dpiX = 96.0 * VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleX; Здесь dpiX - это NumberSubstitution

Comment: А, понял, конструктор FormattedText, который здесь используется, тоже доступен только с 4.6.2

Comment: Нет, здесь dpiX именно что double, просто вам недоступен конструктор FormattedText, который здесь используется

Comment: @UggoFantozzi, значит надо экспериментировать с другими конструкторами, у меня, к сожалению, сейчас доступа к ПК нету, поэтому не могу посмотреть

Comment: хорошо, буду пробовать

Comment: До .NET 4.6.2 вся эта кухня с dpi недоступна, что может быть не очень хорошо, потому что сейчас это очень актуально, масштабирование в Windows, увеличенный dpi сейчас очень часто используется. Поэтому в первую очередь я бы рассмотрел переход на .NET 4.6.2, как минимум. Если не можете это сделать, пробуйте для начала создать NumberSubstitution просто через конструктор без параметров