# Как сделать снимок окна WPF и закрыть его?

Tags: c#, wpf

Суть такова, через основное окно нажимается кнопка, открывается окно, заполняется, делается скрин, и закрывается(автоматически). А проблема в том, что если код для скрина поместить в Loaded события, то окно не успевает полностью открыться, и на скрине не отображаются данные.
Решение 2-ое, и проблема 2-ая, код для скрина поместил в событие закрытия окна. Если самому закрывать окно кнопкой Х, то скрин получается. А если в конструктор окна, поместить команду Close(), то при вызове окна компилятор ругается что нельзя вызвать Show, после закрытия окна.

В общем, как правильно решить эту проблему. Требуется: открытие, скрин, закрытие.
Сам код окна

```
public PrintWindow(string[] info)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //заполнение окна через массив info
    Close();
}

private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //код для скрина
    double screenLeft = this.Left + 9;//SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
    double screenTop = this.Top + 30;//SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop;
    double screenWidth = this.Width;//SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
    double screenHeight = this.Height;//SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;//SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            string filename = FIO.Text + ".png";
            Opacity = 0;
            g.CopyFromScreen((int)screenLeft, (int)screenTop, 18, 39, /*(int)screenWidth,(int) screenHeight,*/ bmp.Size);
            bmp.Save(filename);
            Opacity = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалейте читающего, что такое *Клос*? *Шов*?

Comment: Вы снимаете без заголовка? Только содержимое окна?

Comment: Да. Шас все на англ перепишу. Шов- Show. открытие окна

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я предлагаю вам пользоваться именно средствами WPF:

```
public static void CreateBitmapFromVisual(Visual target, string fileName)
{
    var bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);
    var renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)bounds.Width,
        (int)bounds.Height,
        96,
        96,
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    var visual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (var context = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        var visualBrush = new VisualBrush(target);
        context.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size));
    }

    renderTarget.Render(visual);
    var bitmapEncoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    bitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));
    using (var stm = File.Create(fileName))
        bitmapEncoder.Save(stm);
}
```

Это позволит сделать снимок независимо от того, что фактически отображается на экране. Но да, вызывать метод нужно только после того как контрол загрузится (событие `Loaded`):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateBitmapFromVisual(this, @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.bmp");
    Close();
}
```

Обратите внимание, здесь вы получаете снимок в исходном масштабе, независимо от настроек масштабирования Windows. Если же вы хотите получить "дословный" снимок, то необходимо получить коэффициенты масштабирования и воспользоваться ими:

```
public static void CreateBitmapFromVisual(Visual target, string fileName)
{
    var bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);
    var scaleX = PresentationSource.FromVisual(target).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
    var scaleY = PresentationSource.FromVisual(target).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
    var renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)(bounds.Width * scaleX),
        (int)(bounds.Height * scaleY),
        96 * scaleX,
        96 * scaleY,
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    ...
```

Comment: Идеально. Спасибо вам ещё раз. Можно с вами как-то связаться?

Comment: Можете попробовать написать мне в чате: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--