# Слои на изображении

Tags: wpf, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как можно реализовать слои на изображении?

Т.е когда на одно изображение накладываются другие изображения.

Есть мысля хранить все изображения в неком списке, а в главном окне отображать изображение, которое получено в результате склейки всех слоев.

Однако, на сколько это верно или WinForms и WPF предоставляют какие-то решения из коробки?

Comment: Не понятно что вы имеете ввиду. Как изображения должны накладываться? Можно пример?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну по аналогии со слоями в том же фотошопе.

Comment: Никогда в жизни не открывал фотошоп

Comment: Если изображения с прозрачностью, то не вижу никаких проблем, просто поместите все `Image` в один `Grid` и установите им нужный `ZIndex`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хм... По идее должно работать. А на WinForms, как подобное достигается? Интереса ради.

Comment: Я в WinForms не умею, но подозреваю, что примерно так же

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хм... А будет ли работать описанный вами для WPF подход, когда изображения имеют разных размер и второе изображение нужно, допустим поместить в угол первого. Смогу ли я это спозиционировать вашим подходом или придется дополнительно выполнить преобразования второго изображения, что бы оно успешно наложилось?

Comment: Сможете, помещайте не в `Grid`, а в `Canvas` и позиционируйте как угодно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81996/discussion-between-iluxa1810-and--nop).

Comment: @АндрейNOP, оформите, как ответ. Я думаю, что по части WPF мне этого хватит.

Answer (score 1):

Просто поместите свои изображения в `Image`, а все `Image` в `Canvas`, установите им необходимые `Canvas.Left`/`Canvas.Top`/`Panel.ZIndex`. Изображения с прозрачностью выводятся так как вы ожидаете, поэтому это сработает как надо.

Comment: А содержимое Canvas можно сохранить в JPG со всеми картинками штатными средствами или нужно самому все это расчитать и создать итоговый Image, а потом сохранить?

Comment: @iluxa1810, можно сделать снимок: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851003/218063

Comment: Вместо BMP можете использовать любой другой энкодер, смотрите список наследников здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: А сником не будет ли масштабирован под окошко программы, игнорируя то, что в канвасе на самом деле здоровенное изображение?

Comment: То что видите на экране — то и будет в файле

Comment: Т.е если мне нужно изображение исходного размера, то снимок мне не подойдет и я должен руками сам формировать результирующий Image?

Comment: А Image разве не подстраивается под размеры помещенного в него изображения?

Comment: Хранит, но если вы говорите, что вашем способом будет напечатано то, что видит пользователь, то он может увидеть окно программы до малых размеров и как я понимаю таким изображение и будет сохранено?

Comment: Я вас не понимаю, если вы пишете какой-то графический редактор, то работайте с изображениями "по настоящему". И нет, GUI-фреймворки не предоставляют средств для редактирования картинок, это не их задача