# Можно ли получить в WPF картинку контролла?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

У меня есть некоторый блок, который является пользовательским элементом управления, который можно перемещать на полотне. Но, можно ли реализовать как бы перемещение картинки блока? То есть я хочу сначала переместить картину блока и уже потом на ее место разместить настоящий блок.

Ниже представлен пример из Visio, есть два блока они соединены, и когда я перемещаю один из блоков, я перемещаю как бы его картинку, она полупрозрачная
[image]

Comment: [Оно?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-user-control)

Comment: @aepot а позволяет ли эта механика сделать эффект перемещения контрола? Я работал с ней не много, кажется это вещь позволяет просто перемещать данные.

Comment: [Дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618048/220553)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну смотрите, вы когда перемещаете файл из одной папки в другую, вы как-бы картинку файла перемещаете, то есть как бы да дубликат, но именно, что это картинка, от нее не требуется функционала никакого, который есть у контролла

Comment: А я вам дал ссылку на что-то "функциональное"? Лишь "картинка" при перетаскивании контролла (`Canvas`), не более)

Comment: Сделать снимок контрола: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851003/218063