# Буквы в нижнем регистре выходят за границы контейнера

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь сохранить текст как картинку (так чтобы визуально не контролировать расположение текста), но указанный контейнер обрезает выступающие части буквы.
С рукописными шрифтами это происходит, когда размер шрифта очень большой:

```
<Border VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF5D81AC" BorderThickness="1">
     <TextBlock FontFamily="Abiggail" Text="zz" FontSize="150"/>   
</Border>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У стандартных шрифтов такое происходит с курсивом:

```
<Border VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF5D81AC" BorderThickness="1">
   <Glyphs VerticalAlignment   ="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FontUri             = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\ARIAL.TTF"
        FontRenderingEmSize = "56"
        StyleSimulations    = "ItalicSimulation"
        UnicodeString       = "Hello!"
        Fill                = "SteelBlue"
        />
</Border>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Padding - не выход, т.к.  рукописный орнамент может быть непредсказуемым. Тем более в TextBox'е не помогает даже Padding:

```
<TextBox FontFamily="Abiggail" Text="zz"/>
<TextBox FontFamily="Abiggail" Text="zz" FontSize="150"/>
<TextBox FontFamily="Abiggail" Text="zz" FontSize="150" Padding="15,0,0,0"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что тут можно сделать?

Comment: Возможно как-то поможет этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824329/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP я бы даже сказал, что это дубликат, закрывайте.

Comment: @aepot, ну, вроде, не дубликат. Одно дело изменить размер, другое — добиться, чтобы ничего не обрезалось, не выходило за пределы контейнера